# Linking to a placemark in embedded Google Map

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, kml

I'm not sure if this is even possible or if I just don't know the proper way to search for it.

I have created a map of places and have it embedded on my site. I am using a KML file because this is a map that I will need to easily update in the future.

On the site, I have a list of places shown on the map and I would like for a user to be able to click a link and have the map zoom in show that place.

I've searched all over and can not find an answer on how to do it.

Comment: How did you "embed the map on your site"? What does you KML look like (how complex/big is the file)? [example of map with "sidebar" from KML](http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_geoxml3_kmltest_linktoB.html?filename=us_states.xml) (uses the "third party KML parser [geoxml3](https://code.google.com/p/geoxml3/))

Comment: I am embedding the map with jquery and my KML is pretty simple. It's 7 place markers, 4 of which I would like to link to. Would it be easier to hardcode those place markers into the site because they won't change? And then can I use KML to load the ones that will change and not be linked to? This is my first time working with the Google Maps API and I am a little lost.

Comment: Is your KML publicly available?  Can you provide a link or add it to your question?  This is not really the place for broad general technical questions, there are lots of ways to do this, which one is "easier" depends on who is doing the implementing.

Comment: Here is a link to the site I am working on.


[http://triplethreatpress.com/new/shop.php](http://triplethreatpress.com/new/shop.php)

As you can see, the map and locations are working fine. What I would like to do is have a text link with the addresses at the top that will open that location on the map.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using [maplace.js](http://maplacejs.com) and linking to the map location with the menu feature. It does exactly what I want it to do.